# Use pytorch on Alpine

Tags: docker, pytorch, glibc, alpine-linux

I have a docker image in alpine, and need to use pytorch on it. However, as stated in the pytorch website, it requires glibc to run, otherwise it will give error below

```
import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 189, in <module>
    _load_global_deps()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 142, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: Error relocating /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libgomp-7c85b1e2.so.1: pthread_attr_setaffinity_np: symbol not found
```

I've tried to install glibc from https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.29-r0/glibc-2.29-r0.apk, but error info stay the same.